# What is the difference between CreateDate and RecorDate in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Recently, I was doing some SQL queries in an old ERP system that we have and I noticed these two columns that looks almost identical but they slightly change by microseconds and some of them by a large margin of days.

```
select id, RecordDate, CreateDate, DATEDIFF(DAY,CreateDate,RecordDate) as TimeDifference from items


id    RecordDate                 CreateDate                 TimeDifference 
 0    2014-03-28 17:29:35.557   2014-03-28 17:29:35.557          0
 1    2014-04-11 12:13:17.320   2014-04-11 12:13:17.320          0
 2    2014-05-08 10:15:42.670   2014-05-08 10:15:42.670          0
 3    2014-03-17 18:58:28.480   2018-01-10 13:22:33.827         1395
 4    2014-03-17 18:58:30.207   2018-01-02 20:11:49.327         1387
```

How is this RecordDate and CreateDate being differentiated?

Comment: How do we know? We didn't design the table, and we didn't write the INSERT or UPDATE statements that wrote the data.

Comment: I think you'll have to ask the ERP author or look at the source code to find out how/when those fields are being written to. `RecordDate` is *probably* when something happened, while `CreateDate` is when the record was written to the table. But that's only a WAG.

Comment: It is somewhat common to have 2 date/time columns in tables, both are set with the same value when inserted, but thereafter only one is updated as some change is made to existing data. The columns might be called CreatedDate and LastUpdatedDate or similar. So I expect that is true for this table but the column names are a little different.